# "circular" dependencies in Apache ivy

Tags: ant, ivy, circular-dependency

I have a simple ant build with the following ivy dependencies:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
  <info organisation="de.jflex" module="examples.simple"/>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org="junit" name="junit" rev="4.12"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.guava" name="guava" rev="26.0-jre"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.truth" name="truth" rev="0.36"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

`ant build` fails with:

> circular dependency found: com.google.truth#truth;0.36->com.google.testing.compile#compile-testing;0.12->com.google.truth#truth;0.35

But it's not a hard circular dependency: they depend on different versions. How do I work around this?

Comment: Full logs: https://travis-ci.org/jflex-de/jflex/jobs/440706014

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting a warning, which is also a default value of the [`circularDependencyStrategy`setting](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/settings/settings.html). If you really want to hide this, you can set that attribute to [`ignore`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/concept.html#circular). But it looks like that even if you change this, dependecy resolution will still fail, due to unresolved `com.google.gwt#gwt-user;2.8.0: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.8.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4`